# Name of Octonions With Biquaternion Coefficients?

Tags: terminology, division-algebras

Ordinary [biquaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biquaternion) are quaternions $(\mathbb{H})$ whose coefficients are complex $(\mathbb{C})$.  What is the name, analogous to "biquaternions", for octonions $(\mathbb{O})$ whose coefficients are ordinary biquaternions?

If there is no such name, what is the most concise descriptive phrase?

Comment: Interesting question. I wouldn't argue this is the natural extension of the definition of biquaternions though... That would be octonians whose coefficients are *quaternions*, and not necessarily whose coefficients are *ordinary biquaternions*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things you are talking about are $\mathbb H \otimes \mathbb C$ and $\mathbb O \otimes (\mathbb H \otimes \mathbb C)$ (tensor products over $\mathbb R$).  I would call the former the *complexified quaternions* or the *complex quaternion algebra* (there is a unique quaternion algebra over $\mathbb C$ up to isomorphism, namely $M_2(\mathbb C)$.  (I have never heard the term "biquaternion" for this, and I am reasonably well acquainted with modern terminology regarding quaternion algebras, though I have not read the old works of Hamilton, Cayley, etc.)

By analogy, I would call $\mathbb O \otimes (\mathbb H \otimes \mathbb C)
\simeq \mathbb O \otimes M_2(\mathbb C)$ something like the *complexified quaternionic octonions*, or possibly the *two-by-two complex octonionic matrices*, depending on how I represented them.  (The latter would be as $M_2(\mathbb O_{\mathbb C})$, where $\mathbb O_{\mathbb C} = \mathbb O \otimes \mathbb C$
is the (split) octonion algebra over $\mathbb C$.  Such tensor products have been examined
(in greater generality) [in this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869301987733), but I did not see a specific name for these objects, so I would venture that there is no name in common modern usage. (Admittedly, I just skimmed that paper quickly, so you might want to take a closer look.)

Comment: "biquaternion" occurs 4 times in the paper you, yourself, linked to and it has 10,000 hits on google including Wolfram Mathworld and Encyclopedia Britannica as well as Wikipedia.  So "biquaternionic octonions" would seem to be proper usage.  Moreover, even if we were to disqualify "biquaternion", wouldn't the phrase "complexified quaternionic octonions" (2*4*8 = 64 real coefficients) be more specific than "quaternionic octonions" (4*8 = 32 real coefficients)?

Comment: @JamesBowery Sorry, I misread the question---I was thinking you were looking to extend the octonions with quaternionic coefficients, not "biquaternion" coefficients.  Edited answer.

Comment: @JamesBowery For the other part of your comment, yes, I am not claiming people don't use "biquaternion," just that it is not too common in modern studies of quaternion/division algebras.  And I believe the usage of "biquaternion" in the paper I link to means something different (namely, the tensor product of two quaternion algebras) than how you are using it.

Comment: The paper "Standard model physics from an algebra?" by C. Furey calls  $\mathbb R \otimes  \mathbb C  \otimes \mathbb H  \otimes \mathbb O$ "The Dixon algebra". "Its connection to particle physics was studied
indirectly by Casalbuoni et al., and later much more extensively by Dixon." That's in "Division algebras: octonions, quaternions, complex numbers and the algebraic design of physics." by G. Dixon.  Is this related or perhaps, even, identical to $\mathbb O \otimes (\mathbb H \otimes \mathbb C)$?

Comment: @JamesBowery I haven't thought about tensor product of non-associative algebras, but yes, I believe that's the same thing.

Comment: If you can verify the identity and modify your answer to include that identity and "Dixon algebra" as physics argot citing Furey, I'll accept your answer.